# Mobile website form Validation

Tags: javascript, windows-mobile, mobile-safari, mobile-website, mobilewebforms

What method/plugin you would prefer for Mobile form validation. Even on older mobile who has decent JavaScript support.

I'm not using jQuery Mobile or Sencha. I need standalone solution and error should come as alert box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "required"  and "pattern" tag in input field.

For exaple:

```
 <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"  required="required" pattern="[A-z]{3}" size="40"/>
```